# How can we increase Commissioning/Deploying timeout for nodes in MAAS?

Tags: maas

I'm emulating ARM virtual machines on `x86_64`. While commissioning those VMs, I'm hitting timeouts (after 20 mins) causing 'Failed commissioning' error. In `/usr/share/maas/maas/settings.py`, `COMMISSIONING_TIMEOUT` is set to 60 mins.

*Is this a bug in MAAS or is there any other way to set its value?*

Answer (score 2):

It seems, commissioning_timeout in settings.py doesn't effect. It is hard coded within MAAS code. To change the timeout, I updated '`NODE_STATUS.COMMISSIONING`' in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/maasserver/node_status.py`
Then restarted all maas services:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart maas-regiond maas-rackd maas-proxy maas-dhcpd
```

Note: MAAS version `2.1.2`

Answer (score 2):

It's been a few years since this post, but you can now modify the value programmatically via the MAAS CLI/API with recent versions of MAAS. You will need to authenticate to the CLI/API first, [those instructions may be found here](https://maas.io/docs/try-out-the-maas-cli). I confirmed this with 2.8-2.9 here, both packaged versions and snap verisons:

```
maas admin maas get-config name=node_timeout
Success.
Machine-readable output follows:
30
```

Now let's update that default:

```
maas admin maas set-config name=node_timeout value=120
Success.
Machine-readable output follows:
OK
```

And to verify:

```
maas admin maas get-config name=node_timeout              
Success.
Machine-readable output follows:
120
```

You can find the API endpoints for `set-config` and `get-config` in the MAAS API documentation, under [MAAS Server](https://maas.io/docs/api#maas-server).

Comment: Besides, this option is only supported by more recent MaaS. I think it is perhaps 2.5 or higher?

Comment: @tai271828 MAAS 2.1 is an obsolete release, and wouldn't be supported anyway. 

See the MAAS release timeline page for currently supported releases.

https://launchpad.net/maas/+series